# why does twitter implement a full screen image like this

Tags: css

There is a full screen image in the front page of twitter.In the source code,they do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="front-bg">
<img class="front-image" src="xxx.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.front-bg {
position: fixed;
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
left: -50%;
}
.front-bg img {
margin: auto;
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Why do they set top/left property to the ".front-bg img"?
And if I change something like this:

```
.front-bg {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.front-bg img {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

It works as well. Why do they set width 200% instead?

Answer (score 1):

> { top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; }

This part is not used on desktop at all as this image does not have position property set, perhaps it's used on different devices with additional media queries?

I'd say the reason behind 200%/200% and positioning margin has to do something with the preffered way for centering the image. With %100/%100 scenario image would be always left aligned to the left border of browser window on smaller screens. By applying

> margin: 0 auto; min-width: 50%;

they make it as wide as browser window and always centered.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to account for different screens with different aspect ratios so the centre of the picture is always centred and has enough 'spare' on the edges whether the screen is portrait or landscape.

Comment: I thought this too.. but trying the edits mentioned above and adjusting the window size on both of the versions seems to have the same effect.

Comment: My best guess then would be that while the edited code may work on your browser there may be older browsers where it doesn't work and this is to get round a bug.

Comment: Can you guys do some test on the old ie browser? Im from China. Due to those communist bastards, its kind of hard to visit twitter using ietester.